# I'd like to develop a data-driven app on Phonegap. Do I need to download a separate SDK for every platform?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

The app is meant to run on all major smartphone platforms namely android, windows mobile, symbian, iPhone, Blackberry and on tablets as well. I have eclipse (version 1.2.2.20100216-1730) installed with Android SDK already configured and installed.

Can someone guide me? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you want to do this yourself - you'll need to setup an environment (with SDK, compilers, simulator, etc...) for each target you want to deploy to - e.g. xCode for iOS + SDK, Eclipse for Android + SDK, Eclipse for BB +SDK, etc...

but, if you use the standard (and not your own plugins), there are now cloud services where you upload your html/css/js code and they'll deliver a compiled app for each environment. The first one was [PhoneGap Build](https://build.phonegap.com/), but I've already seen others that provide this service as well.

Hope this helps!

Comment: So the first option would obviously include more efforts, but once the app is complete for one platform then I do not have to do further coding for another platform. In my situation, I have android SDK and emulator so all I have to do is to setup an environment (with SDK, compilers, simulator, etc...) for each target I want to deploy after completing the code of my app...right?

Comment: the coding HTML/JS/CSS is the same - only in theory - my answer is more related to the actual compilation of native apps per platform. Since you already have Android SDK, you can compile those .apk files by yourself! Of course, if you then want the iOS .ipa, you'll need an OSX machine, xCode framework, iOS SDK and don't forget - pay up for the SDK Developers program... That's a lot of overhead - the reason I also suggested the cloud compile solution that gives you something immediately... All a question of how many resources you got to invest ;)

Comment: Also my application includes controls like Data Grid and Tab controls(just like in desktop or web applications). Do we have any option in HTML or JS to include such controls in a smartphone app?